# Django REST Framework slow on Gunicorn

Tags: django, performance, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I deployed a new application made on **Django REST Framework** running with **Gunicorn**.

The application is deployed on 4 different servers and they are listening on a port (8001) which is consumed by an HAProxy load balancer.

Unfortunately I am suffering many performance problems: many requests takes seconds to be served, even 30 or 60 seconds.

Sometimes even the **basic entry endpoint** (like https://my.api/api/v2 which basically returns the list of the available endpoints) **requires 10/20 seconds to respond**.

I don't think the problem is the load balancer because I have latencies connecting directly to any backend servers with my client, so bypassing the load balancer.

And I don't think the problem is the database because the call to https://my.api/api/v2 as guest (not logged with any user) shouldn't make any database query.

This is a performance test made with **hey** (https://github.com/rakyll/hey) on the basic endpoint **without authorization**:

```
me@staging2:~$ hey -n 10000 -c 100 https://my.api/api/v2/

Summary:
  Total:    38.9165 secs
  Slowest:  18.6772 secs
  Fastest:  0.0041 secs
  Average:  0.3099 secs
  Requests/sec: 256.9604

  Total data:   20870000 bytes
  Size/request: 2087 bytes

Response time histogram:
  0.004 [1] |
  1.871 [9723]  |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  3.739 [0] |
  5.606 [175]   |■
  7.473 [0] |
  9.341 [35]    |
  11.208 [29]   |
  13.075 [0]    |
  14.943 [0]    |
  16.810 [0]    |
  18.677 [37]   |


Latency distribution:
  10% in 0.0054 secs
  25% in 0.0122 secs
  50% in 0.0322 secs
  75% in 0.2378 secs
  90% in 0.3417 secs
  95% in 0.3885 secs
  99% in 8.5935 secs

Details (average, fastest, slowest):
  DNS+dialup:   0.0021 secs, 0.0041 secs, 18.6772 secs
  DNS-lookup:   0.0001 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0123 secs
  req write:    0.0001 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0153 secs
  resp wait:    0.3075 secs, 0.0039 secs, 18.6770 secs
  resp read:    0.0001 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0150 secs

Status code distribution:
  [200] 10000 responses
```

This is my Gunicorn configuration:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:8001'
backlog = 2048

workers = 1
worker_class = 'sync'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 120
keepalive = 5

spew = False

daemon = False
pidfile = None
umask = 0
user = None
group = None
tmp_upload_dir = None

errorlog = '-'
loglevel = 'debug'
accesslog = '-'
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
```

And Gunicorn is currently running with the following command:

```
/path/to/application/bin/python3 /path/to/application/bin/gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.production -c /path/to/application/settings/gunicorn_conf.py --user=deployer --log-file=/path/to/application/django-application-gunicorn.log --chdir /path/to/application/django-application --daemon wsgi:application
```

What tests I can do to find out what is causing my performance problems?

Comment: I don't think drf itself caused this issue, try using `django-debugtoolbar`, it might help

Comment: It's working fine in local environment ?
Maybe you can try with worker=2*cpu count ?

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. I increased the number of workers to 8 and now the API seems to work faster. But I wish to test it tomorrow morning when it will be stressed by users. I will update you!

Comment: Thanks Mohammad! Today the API seems to be much more rapid!